# C++ return value on concurrent queue pushing functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++11, promise

After receiving answers to a previous question on logging on a different thread, I am currently at the following bit of code (note: the concurrent_queue here is from ppl, but any other concurrent_queue should work):

```
class concurrentFuncQueue
    {
    private:
        typedef std::function<void()> LambdaFunction;
        mutable concurrency::concurrent_queue<LambdaFunction> functionQueue;
        mutable std::atomic<bool> endcond;
        LambdaFunction function;
        std::thread thd;
    public:
        concurrentFuncQueue() : endcond(false), thd([=]{
            while (endcond != true)
            {
                if (functionQueue.try_pop( function ))
                {
                    function(); //note: I am popping a function and adding () to execute it
                }
            }
        }){}
        ~concurrentFuncQueue() { functionQueue.push([=]{ endcond = true; }); thd.join(); }
        void pushFunction(LambdaFunction function) const { functionQueue.push(function); }
    };
```

Basically the functions I push are run on a different thread sequentially (ex. a logging function) as to avoid performance issues on the main thread.

Current usage is along the following:

```
static concurrentFuncQueue Logger;
vector<char> outstring(256);
Logger.pushFunction([=]{ OutputDebugString(debugString.c_str()) });
```

Great so far. I can push functions on to a concurrent queue that will run my functions sequentially on a separate thread.

One thing I also need to have, but currently don't are return values so that ex (pseudo-code):

```
int x = y = 3;
auto intReturn = Logger.pushFunction([=]()->int { return x * y; });
```

will push x * y on to the concurrent queue, and after the pop and completion of the function (on the other thread), returns the value calculated to the caller thread.

(I understand that I'll be blocking the caller thread until the pushed function is returned. That is exactly what I want)

I get the feeling that I might have to use something along the line of std::promise, but sadly my current low understanding of them prevent me from formulating something codable.

Any ideas? Thoughts on the above C++ code and any other comments are also much welcome (please just ignore the code completely if you feel another implementation is more appropriate or solves the problem).

Comment: The direction of `std::promise` and `std::promise::get_future()` is the right one. If you return a `std::future` from `pushFunction`, the user can decide whether they actually want to block (`.get()`) or not.

Comment: Not really related to the real question (there is already a valid answer for that) but in your example `endcond` doesn't have to be atomic since the value is only ever changed from your single worker thread. Atomics are faster than mutexes for this purpose but are still drastically slower than a standard variable.

Comment: @John5342 Thanks for the comment; I've been keeping the bool atomic because I'm still a bit uncomfortable with working with threads, but I'll keep your comment in mind and change it to a standard bool. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something along the lines of:

```
template<typename Foo>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Foo()>::type> pushFunction(Foo&& f) {
    using result_type = typename std::result_of<Foo()>::type; // change to typedef if using is not supported
    std::packaged_task<result_type()> t(f);
    auto ret_fut = t.get_future();
    functionQueue.push(std::move(t));
    return ret_fut;
}
```

For this to work you need to make your `LambdaFunction` a type-erased function handler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that seems to solve the push function; I'm not quite sure how I'd go about implementing a type-erased version of the LambdaFunction typedef, could you if possible provide an example?

Comment: I can think of a way to perhaps circumvent the need for a type-erased function by wrapping up the task in a void function and sending that into the queue, but your suggestion of redoing the LambdaFunction as a type-erased function seems more efficient.

Comment: @dk123 By wrapping them into a void function you would be back to the beginning where you couldn't use a return value, wouldn't you? You can find an example of a type erased function wrapper here in my repo. https://github.com/StephanDollberg/BAM/blob/master/include/bam/detail/function_wrapper.hpp

Comment: Couldn't you push the void function and return ret_fut? I was somewhat thinking along those lines, but I'll take a look at the function wrapper. Thanks!